# argparse optional parameter within positional

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

With `argparse` I would like to be able to mix optional parameters with multiple positional parameters, e.g., like `svn` allows:

```
svn ls first/path -r 1000 second/path
```

At the moment, this is not officially supported by Python (c.f. http://bugs.python.org/issue14191). I wrote this workaround and I am now wondering, if a) there is a better/easier/more elegant way to do it, and b) if someone can see something in the code that might break it under certain cirumstances:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                          

import argparse as ap                                                           

p = ap.ArgumentParser()                                                         
p.add_argument('-v', action='store_true')                                       
p.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')                                       
p.add_argument('files', nargs='*', action='append')                             
p.add_argument('remainder', nargs=ap.REMAINDER, help=ap.SUPPRESS)                  

args = p.parse_args()                                                              
while args.remainder != []:                                                        
    args = p.parse_args(args.remainder, args)                                      

print(args)
```

Usage example:

```
./test.py a b -v c d
```

Output:

```
Namespace(files=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], l=False, remainder=[], v=True)
```

Comment: There's a version of the workaround in 14191 that you can download and add to your code - without modifying your `argparse`.  You may need it if you need to define more `positionals`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [parse_known_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) instead of including a `remainder`:

```
import argparse as ap                                                           

p = ap.ArgumentParser()                                                         
p.add_argument('-v', action='store_true')                                       
p.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')                                       
p.add_argument('files', nargs='*', action='append')                             

args, unknown = p.parse_known_args()
while unknown:
    args, unknown = p.parse_known_args(unknown, args) 

print(args)
```

yields

```
Namespace(files=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], l=False, v=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `files=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` or `files=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`?  In other words should

```
./test.py a b -v c d 
./test.py a b -v c -l d 
./test.py -l a b -v c d
```

give different `files` lists of lists.

`append` with a `*` positional usually doesn't make sense, since you can't repeat a positional argument.  But with this recursive application, it does work.  But if the sublists are important, why not use multiple positional arguments.

On the other hand, to get a flat list of 'files', you could do several things:

You could flatten the list after parsing (e.g. `args.files=list(itertools.chain(*args.files))`)

You could use `p.add_argument('files', nargs='?', action='append')`.  This iterates over each `file` string.

```
./test.py a b -l c d -v e f
Namespace(files=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], l=True, remainder=[], v=True)
```

---

You could replicate the http://bugs.python.org/issue14191 patch by removing the positional from the initial parse.  In this case the `extras` can be simply inserted into `args`.

A disadvantage of this is that the `usage` and `help` known nothing about the positional, requiring a custom `usage` and/or `description` parameter.

```
usage = usage: %(prog)s [-h] [-v] [-l] [files [files ...]]
description = 'files: may be given in any order'
p = ap.ArgumentParser(usage=usage, description=description)                            
p.add_argument('-v', action='store_true')                                       
p.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')                                       
args, extras = p.parse_known_args() 
args.files = extras
```

---

unutbu's answer does not preserve the groupings.  They are lost the first time through:

Namespace(files=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']], l=True, v=True)

It could be changed to give a flat list:

```
p = ap.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-v', action='store_true')
p.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')
p.add_argument('files', nargs='*')

args, unknown = p.parse_known_args()
args.files.extend(unknown)
```

The iteration isn't needed, since `optionals` are handled the first time through.  All that is left in `unknown` are `files`.

In sum - to preserve the groupings, your solution appears to be the best.